# Checking null vs. matching in a Java/Scala project

Tags: java, scala, null

In my Scala class I am checking to see if a java object's method will return a string or null. What is the best way to do this check? Should I continue to just check if the method returns null like someone would do in Java or should I be wrapping it in an Option and be using Scala's matching of Options.

Answer (score 5):

In Scala, you should use `Option[String]` to make it clear:

```
val stringOpt: Option[String] = Option(someJavaMethodThatReturnsNull())
```

And then use pattern matching or the functions of `Option`.